# PDF Viewer vs Web Viewer andriod

Tags: android-layout, pdf, android-webview

Which one is Best for my Android Tutorial App (pdf viewer or web viewer) . Its a Programming tutorial app so which component i use for my app? or another suggestion to develop tutorial app.

Answer (score 0):

I use pdf viewer instead of webview because pdf show all image or content offline but webview is not showing the images offline. One more Problem occur to creating a block for code between pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you have prepared your content in word/doc/pdf then the pdf viewer is best.
If you have prepared your content in HTML like web pages or website, it's best to go with the webview.